# How can call to refresh my fragment class in another method (I Tried all the solution on stackoverflow)

Tags: java, android

I have a void method synchronizeNum(String String String) Which will be trigger in onViewCreated , This Line.

```
 new DisDepartmentSender(myView.getContext(), urlAddress, accountEmail, departmentName).execute();
```

It will get data from database and finally pass back and set the data into this method synchronizeNum (String String String).After i set the data i wish to display it using TextView. I think the only way is execute again onViewCreated method, since we cannot setText inside synchronizeNum method.I have tried many detach and attach method inside the method but the problem is it get NullPointer i donno how to solve i have been looking around for 1 day just for this little problem. I need you guys help please.

### CurrentDepartmentView FragmentClass

```
    package com.example.cheng.freequeue.DisplayDepartmentStatus;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.example.cheng.freequeue.R;

    /**
     * Created by cheng on 11/4/2018.
     */

    public class CurrentStatusView extends Fragment {
        DisDepartmentList disDepartmentList=new DisDepartmentList();
        final static String urlAddress = "https://kokcheng95.000webhostapp.com/departmentStatus.php";
        private String CompanyName, accountEmail, departmentName, imageUrl;
        private String num1room1, num2room2, num3room3, num1, num2, num3, room1, room2, room3;
        private final Handler handler = new Handler();
        View myView;
        Context c;
        ViewGroup container;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        TextView company_name, department_name, num_1, num_2, num_3, room_1, room_2, room_3;
        de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView image_department;



        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.current_department_view, container, false);
            this.container=container;
            company_name = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.company_name);
            department_name = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.department_name);
            image_department = (de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.image_department);
           num_1 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.number1);
            num_1 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.number1);
            num_2 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.number2);
            num_3 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.number3);
            room_1 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.room1);
            room_2 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.room2);
            room_3 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.room3);
            new DisDepartmentSender(myView.getContext(), urlAddress, accountEmail, departmentName).execute();
            //Set data
            company_name.setText("Company Name : " + CompanyName);
            department_name.setText("Department : " + departmentName);
            PicassoClientDepartment.dowloadImage(myView.getContext(), imageUrl, image_department);



            //Set Data
            num_1.setText(num1);
            num_2.setText(num1);
            num_3.setText(num1);
            room_1.setText(room1);
            room_2.setText(room2);
            room_3.setText(room3);





            return myView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

            if (bundle != null) {
                CompanyName = bundle.getString("CompanyName", "noText");
                accountEmail = bundle.getString("accountEmail", "noText");
                departmentName = bundle.getString("departmentName", "noText");
                imageUrl = bundle.getString("imageUrl", "noText");


            }


        }


        public void synchronizeNum(String num1room1, String num2room2, String num3room3) {

            String path1[] = num1room1.split("_");
            String path2[] = num2room2.split("_");
            String path3[] = num3room3.split("_");


            num1 = path1[0];
            room1 = path1[1];
            num2 = path2[0];
            room2 = path2[1];
            num3 = path3[0];
            room3 = path3[1];



    /*       Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("CurrentStatusView");
                FragmentTransaction fragTransaction =   (getActivity()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
                fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
                fragTransaction.commit();*/
        }


        public void setNum1room1(String num1room1) {
            this.num1room1 = num1room1;
        }
        public String getNum1room1() {
            return num1room1;
        }
        public void setNum2room2(String num2room2) {
            this.num2room2 = num2room2;
        }

        public String getNum2room2() {
            return num2room2;
        }


        public void setNum3room3(String num3room3) {
            this.num3room3 = num3room3;
        }

        public String getNum3room3() {
            return num3room3;
        }

    }
```

### current_department_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.cheng.freequeue.LoginPage">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/department_name"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Department : Orthopedic"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.163" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.458">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_margin="0.1sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:text="Number"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="40dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0.1sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:text="Room"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#080808"
                    android:textSize="40dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/number1"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="0.1sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape_body"
                    android:text="1001"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/room1"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0.1sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape_body"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#080808"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/number2"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="0.1sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape_body"
                    android:text="1002"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/room2"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0.1sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape_body"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#080808"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/number3"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="0.1sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape_body"
                    android:text="1003"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/room3"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0.1sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape_body"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#080808"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_booking"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#d7b9b9b9"
            android:text="BOOKING"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.965" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/image_department"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.015"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.048"
            app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/company_name"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Company Name: TNB"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.064" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This Line Error ,NullPointer

```
Fragment currentFragment=getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("CurrentStatusView");
```

Logcat error

```
    04-12 20:52:13.112 3021-3021/com.example.cheng.freequeue E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.example.cheng.freequeue.DisplayDepartmentStatus.CurrentStatusView.synchronizeNum(CurrentStatusView.java:104)
                at com.example.cheng.freequeue.DisplayDepartmentStatus.DisDepartmentParse.onPostExecute(DisDepartmentParse.java:64)
                at com.example.cheng.freequeue.DisplayDepartmentStatus.DisDepartmentParse.onPostExecute(DisDepartmentParse.java:18)
                at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
                at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5166)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create an interface for updating data.

```
public interface SynchronizeCallback {
  void synchronizeNum(String num1room1, String num2room2, String num3room3);
}
```

Your fragment should implement this interface.

Also set the text to the TextViews inside synchronizeNum():

```
num_1.setText(num1);
num_2.setText(num1);
num_3.setText(num1);
room_1.setText(room1);
room_2.setText(room2);
room_3.setText(room3);
```

Pass the interface to your task when you create it:

```
new DisDepartmentSender(myView.getContext(), urlAddress, accountEmail, departmentName, this).execute();
```

In `onPostExecute` of your `AsyncTask` call

`syncronizeCallback.updateValues(newNum1room1, newNum2room2, newNum3room3);`

Then you should see the new data.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the return value ;) add `void` as return value of this function.

Comment: new DisDepartmentSender(myView.getContext(), urlAddress, accountEmail, departmentName, this).execute();

i need need to pass *this* as argument? or *this* need to be declared ? if yes please guide me sir . Thank for your time

Comment: You need to pass `this` because you have to pass your `SynchronizeCallback` to your `AsyncTask`. `this` is just the `CurrentStatusView` which implements this interface.

Comment: what parameter should i use here ? ibb.co/mG58CS ?

Comment: As I said you have to use `SynchronizeCallback`.